# Regex: Find multiple matching strings in all lines

Tags: regex, string, replace, character, match

I'm trying to match multiple strings in **a single line** using regex in Sublime Text 3.
I want to match all values and replace them with `null.`
Part of the string that I'm matching against:

```
"userName":"MyName","hiScore":50,"stuntPoints":192,"coins":200,"specialUser":false
```

List of strings that it should match:

```
"MyName"
50
192
200
false
```

Result after replacing:

```
"userName":null,"hiScore":null,"stuntPoints":null,"coins":null,"specialUser":null
```

Is there a way to do this without using *sed* or any other substitution method, but just by matching the wanted pattern in regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this find pattern:

```
:(.*?)(,|$)
```

And this replace pattern:

```
:null\2
```

The first group will match any symbol (dot) zero or more times (asterisk) with this last quantifier lazy (question mark), this last part means that it will match as little as possible. The second group will match either a comma or the end of the string. In the replace pattern, I substitute the first group with null (as desired) and I leave the symbol matched by the second group unchanged.

Comment: Good answer but a problem with this would be that it leaves a comma after the last substitution which I do not think the OP will want

Comment: It doesn't put a comma after the last substitution because it will just copy the symbol it finds, either a comma or the dollar sign. I tried it myself.

Comment: I apologize, the regex tester I was using was broken then, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative on amaurs answer where it doesn't put the comma in after the last substitution:

```
:\K(.*?)(?=,|$)
```

And this replacement pattern:

```
null
```

This works like amaurs but starts matching after the colon is found (using the \K to reset the match starting point) and matches until a comma of new line (using a positive look ahead).

I have tested and this works in Sublime Text 2 (so should work in Sublime Text 3)

Another slightly better alternative to this is:

```
(?<=:).+?(?=,|$)
```

which uses a positive lookbehind instead of resetting the regex starting point

Another good alternative (so far the most efficient here):

```
:\K[^,]*
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help.

Find: `(?<=:)[^,]*`
Replace: `null`